# How do I change <img src=""> value conditionally? | Razor CSHTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I'd like to set the *src* value to *ImgLink* if the number of elements in my iList is >= 7
and set it to an empty string if not.

I tried this

```
<div><img src=@Model.SlideshowItems.Count >= 7 ? "@UrlResolver.Current.GetUrl(Model.SlideshowItems[6].ImgLink)" : ""></div>
```

[image: But this error shows up:]

Comment: Under HTML5, `<img>`'s  `src=""` attribute _cannot be empty_, as per the HTML rules. Instead, don't render an `<img />` at all, or use a stub `data: `URI for a 1x1px transparent image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
@{
    string src = "img/exampleDefault.png";
    if (//logic)
    {
        src = "img/example2.png";
    }
}

<div><img src=@src></div>
```

you can reduce the logic to one line:

```
@{
    string src = //logic ? "img/example1.png" : "img/example2.png";
}
```